# Como mapear una vista en Enitiy Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, vistas

Necesito mapear una vista en `EF6` ya que el proyecto debe ser en `.Net Framework`.
Hace no demasiado hice algo parecido en `EF Core 5` de esta forma:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<StockWeb>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasNoKey();
        entity.ToView("Vis_MB_EstocsWEB");
    });

}
```

Pero en `EF 6` el la clase `ModelBuilder` no existe, es la `DbModelBuilder` y esta no contiene los métodos `.HasNoKey()` ni `.ToView()`.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Comment: Me podrías mostrar lo que estas haciendo, en EF 6?

Comment: Solo pretendo mapear una vista de SQL Server, pongamos que tengo una vista con los campos id, nombre, direccion (evidentemente esta vista no tiene ningun sentido, solo es por poner un ejemplo) y quiero mapear los datos a la entidad <cliente>, en EF Core, lo hacia como en el ejemplo de la pregunta, pero en EF6 el cual necesito usar, no puedo hacerlo de la misma manera ya que la clase ModelBuilder no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas de la siguiente manera:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasNoKey().ToView("MySqlView");
}
```

Comment: El usuario aclara que esos métodos no existen en EF6